# when is the embedded svg actually loaded, and how can i check if its loaded

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg, addeventlistener

i've embedded svg in html object tag. i've come to a situation where i need to check if the svg in the object element is actually loaded.

```
<object id="object_id" data='some_svg.svg'></object>
```

i tried to check it using the following code.

```
document.getElementById('object_id').contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]
```

in various case:

**case 1:**

```
<object id="object_id" data="some_svg.svg">
    #document
</object
```

**case2:**

```
<object id="object_id" data="some_svg.svg">
    #document
        <svg>
            // content of the svg path etc.
        </svg>
</object
```

how can i confirm the embedded svg is loaded properly.

Note: addEventListener does not solve the problem. the image is may have loaded before the event listener is actually registered

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `window.load()` method to wait for the `DOM`, and all the `HTML content` to load (all the images, CSS, etc.) and then execute, like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function()
{
    document.getElementById('object_id').contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]
});
```

Comment: i don't have this options as well. i need to check if its loaded or not multiple times. accordingly i would perform some action

Comment: are you loading the svg dynamically (like by clicking a button)? Are you exchanging multiple svgs or is it just one?

Comment: yes i'm loading the svg dynamically. i've multiple svgs. which some of them changes as i click. i'm drawing all the svg to canvas. so i need to check if the svg are preloaded or yet to be loaded